# How to create a config entity that holds multiple URL values?

Tags: 8, entities

I have generated a config entity, and I want to do the following:

Store one or more config entities containing:

- Label
- Node Type
- Link(s)

The objective is a lightweight form that allows admins to create breadcrumb trails for certain node types (similar to how Custom Breadcrumb in D7) that will not be added to a menu (like news, events) but still have a Breadcrumb leading back to a View page or some other page.

For the Link(s) form field, I have:

```
$form['links'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#title' => $this->t('Link to'),
  '#target_type' => 'node',
];
```

The element shows up correctly and is an autocomplete. What I want to do is "Add another", so I can add more than one.

Also, how do I represent this structure in the `.schema.yml` file for this object? Would it be possible to also have the links *sortable* within the form? It would also be great if you could couple a text field to the entity autocomplete, so you could override the breadcrumb title, but I am not concerned with that right now.

Comment: There is no generic add another feature in the form system, you have to build it yourself. Create those in a loop, remember how many you have, increase the count in an ajax callback. Also, entity_autocomplete is *not* a link, it is an entity reference. Not the same thing at all (link widget optionally allows an entity reference, which can be stored as a link but it needs custom processing to also allow urls. In short, to have add another, with sorting, with url + title, you have no choice but to implement that all yourself, from scratch.

Comment: Or since you target content you might consider to store these breadcrumbs in content entities as well and then you have automatically the multi value field widget entity fields are based on.

Comment: So essentially, is your question, How to add an "Add another" button to `$form['links']`???